# Laravel 8 - following system

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to do following system without any laravel library, but when I submit form not saving anything. Where is the problem I don't know.

**My route is:**

```
Route::post('/follow' , [HomeController::class, 'follow'])->name('follow');
```

**My blade is:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('follow')}}" method="POST"></form>
      @csrf
                              
         <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="follower_id"> 
              <input type="submit" class="site-btn" name="following_id" value="Follow"  >                
         </div>
</form>
```

**My controller is:**

```
public function follow(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'follower_id'=>['required'],
            'following_id'=>['required'],
        ]);

        $follower_id = $request->follower_id;
        $following_id = $request->following_id;
        

        $save = Follow::create([
            'following_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'follower_id' => $follower_id,
        ]);

        if($save){
            return back();
        }else{
            return back();
        }
    }
```

**And my User model contains the following relationship**

```
public function follows(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Follow');
    }
```

Comment: <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="follower_id">  is missing value="somthing"

Comment: not working again

Comment: Is `following_id` and `follower_id` in the `$fillable` array of the `Follow` model? (as described [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment))

Comment: It's ok that it's fillable. But need a value to send in the post request. value="{{$some_follow_id}}". If you wont set a value, the server will receive null, and you fillable will set null or nothing.  Please check value="" in the input

Answer (score 1):

remove `</form>` in first line

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('follow')}}" method="POST"></form>
      @csrf
                              
         <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="follower_id"> 
              <input type="submit" class="site-btn" name="following_id" value="Follow"  >                
         </div>
</form>
```

it should be like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('follow')}}" method="POST">
      @csrf
                              
         <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="follower_id"> 
              <input type="submit" class="site-btn" name="following_id" value="Follow"  >                
         </div>
</form>
```